# Поддержка разрыва связи и продолжение передеачи данных

Tags: c++, база-данных, gcc, firebird

У меня имеется база данных, в которую я передаю сообщения типа (id,name,type), используя C++. Когда у меня имеется разрыв связи, я снова присоединяюсь к базе и отправляю все данные сначала. Как сделать так, чтобы запоминался ID, на котором произошел обрыв и при реконнекте отправлять данные начиная с текущего номера?

база firebird, передаю через свои написанные функции, gcc

Comment: >Как сделать так, чтобы запоминался ID, на котором произошел обрыв и при реконнекте отправлять данные начиная с текущего номера?

Сохраняйте текущий `ID` где-то локально, например в глобальную переменную (или файл, если идет взаимодействие между разными процессами), а при разрыве считывайте из нее номер последнего успешно записанного сообщения и продолжайте со следующего.

Comment: Вы бы написали, что за база, как именно передаете (свой протокол, или встроенными средствами), что именно за с++ у Вас (от майкрософта, gcc, embracadero).